# How will create abstract model at the Mongoengine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I need create class which must inherits from others classes. I try do this as structure as:

```
class A(Document):
    field_1 = ...
    field_2 = ...

class B(Document):
    field_a = ... 
    field_b = ... 

class C(A,B):
    specific_field_1 = ...
    specific_field_2 = ...

    meta = {
        'collection': 'class_c',
    }
```

but I don't know decision is complied with the rules. At DBs I will not want collections from `class A` and `class B`.

Please, can anybody help me do it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example on how to create an abstract model in mongoengine (similar to django, by the way):

```
class A(Document):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }
    pass

class B(Document):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }
    pass

class C(A, B):
    specific_field_1 = ...
    specific_field_2 = ...

    meta = {
        'collection': 'class_c',
    }
```

Hope that helps.